# Compiling issue on a reference to @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: java, annotations

I have a java impl class that implements a Dao object.I am trying to annotate @ Transactional on one of the properties .. but i am running into compile time issues at the annotation reference.. what import am i missing.

/**
     * Saves person.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Person save(Person person) {
        return entity.save(person);
    }

Thanks
coolb

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the spring framework jar into your project's classpath.